# TypeScript And Serverless: `this` Undefined When Calling Private Methods from Public Methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, serverless-framework

I am trying to build an AWS Serverless(https://serverless.com/) function in TypeScript.

Specifically, I am defining an abstract class with a single public method that calls some private methods.

Here is my simplified TypeScript class:

```
export abstract class AbstractPayloadProcessor {

    private preHandlePayload(payload) {
        console.log('arrived in prehandle method')
    }

    private postHandlePayload(payload) {
        console.log('arrived in posthandle method')
    }

    protected handleException(error) {
        console.log('Exception has occurred:', error)
    }

    public processPayload(event) {

        // this is the problematic line
        this.preHandlePayload(event.payload)
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

I use webpack transpile this into ES5, which produces the following JavaScript:

```
var AbstractPayloadProcessor = /** @class */ (function () {
    AbstractPayloadProcessor.prototype.preHandlePayload = function (payload) {
        console.log('arrived in prehandle method');
    };
    AbstractPayloadProcessor.prototype.postHandlePayload = function (payload) {
        console.log('arrived in posthandle method');
    };
    AbstractPayloadProcessor.prototype.handleException = function (error) {
        console.log('Exception has occurred:', error);
    };
    AbstractPayloadProcessor.prototype.processPayload = function (event) {
        // this line throws the exception
        this.preHandlePayload(event.payload);
        .
        .
        .
}());
```

The exact exception is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'preHandlePayload' of undefined
```

So far, I have tried setting the webpack config to use ES6 and have tried to use arrow functions to declare the functions in typescript. Both produce the same exception.

The `processPayload` function is being called *somewhere* within the Serverless framework, but I do not know the implementation details. If anyone has experience with the framework and can shed some light on that, I would appreciate it.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: How are you calling the `processPayload` function? That's what determines `this`.

Comment: Ah, good catch. I am actually using the Serverless framework to define an AWS function. I will update the question to include that detail, but I am not too sure how Serverless actually calls your defined logic. I will have to see what i can find

Comment: I can tell you with certainty that it is not related to the use of `abstract`, `public`, or `private`.

Comment: It would help if you showed the class that implements the abstract class and where you are calling the function.

Comment: I can tell you that this has nothing to do with Serverless Framework.

Comment: What's your handler code?

Answer (score 2):

#### Wild guess

I guess that what you're doing is using `someObject.processPayload` and passing it as a callback to some function, or saving it somewhere as an event handler. This function in turn calls `this.preHandlePayload()` but it can't because not having been called properly it has its `this` undefined.

#### More info

There are few possible things that can cause `this` to be undefined inside of a method, and it is not important if it is private or public - because as you can see all of them end up being public after the transpilation.

One possible way is for example inside `method1` if you call `method2()` instead of `this.method2()` then you will have `this` undefined in `method2`.

Another common mistake is saving a method as an event handler or using it as a callback, for example:

```
x.onSomething = object.method;
```

or

```
functionThatTakesCallback(object.method);
```

For those cases to work you either need to pass an anonymous function like:

```
x.onSomething = (...args) => object.method(...args);
```

or binding the method to that object:

```
x.onSomething = object.method.bind(object);
```

Of course, it's hard to tell what's really the problem in your case because you didn't how us how you actually **call** your methods and this is the **calling** not the **definition** of methods that usually puts `undefined` in `this`.